# display in db fields assigned strings rather than integer

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In Database, i have stored/assigned the given name for the string. example,
0- Not Schedule,1-Schedule.

In Admin interface,I want to display only the string name(not schedule, schedule) not for string number (0,1).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you mean you have IntegerField in your model and want to display it as string in admin interface ? (if element is 0 display 'Not schedule', else if element is 1 display 'schedule') ?

Comment: Yes, Show in list display and list filter  django admin interface.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can define new method in your model.

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    schedule = models.IntegerField()

    def as_string(self):
        return 'Not Schedule' if self.schedule is 0 else 'Schedule'
```

and import your model in admin.py file.

```
class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('as_string',)


admin.site.register(Meeting, MeetingAdmin)
```

register it like the above code.

If you only have (0, 1) , you can use Boolean field instead.

for more values.

```
values = {
    0: 'Not Schedule',
    1: 'Schedule',
    2: 'hold'
}


class Meeting(models.Model):
    schedule = models.IntegerField()

    def as_string(self):
        return values[self.schedule]
```

Comment: If we have more than 10 assigned values how can we execute?

Comment: You mean (0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9) instead of (0, 1)

Comment: Why not to make these values static and return them.

Comment: How can display the string name instead of integer list_filter and list_display?

Answer (score 0):

select report.type
    case report.type
        when 0 then 'Not Shedule'
        when 1 then 'Shedule'
    end as TYPE
from
    `report`

Please refer above example.